# Construct an ArrayList of strings in Java as simple as one can in Javascript

Tags: java, syntax, constructor, arraylist

In **JavaScript** I can build an Array of string values like:

```
var stuff = new Array('foo','bar','baz','boz','gaz','goz');
```

or even easier

```
var stuff = 'foo,bar,baz,boz,gaz,goz'.split(',');
```

In **Java** it seems overly verbose and complex... is there an easier way than this?

```
ArrayList<String> stuff = new ArrayList<String>();
stuff.add("foo");
stuff.add("bar");
stuff.add("baz");
stuff.add("boz");
stuff.add("gaz");
stuff.add("goz");
```

In my actual scenario I have 30-40 items going into the ArrayList... I figure there just has to be an easier way! What is the obvious bit I'm overlooking?

Comment: And don't forget `var stuff = ['foo','bar','baz','boz','gaz','goz'];`

Comment: If your curious about Java 7, read more about collection literals here: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/001193.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"foo", "bar", "baz"});` or
`List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("foo,bar,baz".split(","));`

Comment: `Arrays.asList` accepts varargs parameters. So it can be called as `List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz")`. Better yet, do an `import static` for `Arrays.asList` and then it becomes even simpler: `List<String> strings = asList("foo", "bar", "baz")`.

Comment: @abhin4v: That last one is what I use; it very strongly reduces the amount of noise, and it's in the base libraries too.

Comment: For an actual `java.util.ArrayList`, you will need to wrap it in `new `java.util.ArrayList<String>( ... )`.

Comment: What Tom said; asList returns an Arrays.ArrayList which is an immutable wrapper around an array.

Comment: Actually it's not exactly immutable, you can't add or remove from it, but you can change the elements (just like in a normal array).

Answer (score 1):

Arrays.asList() is a good way to get a List implementation, though it is technically not an ArrayList implementation, but an internal type.

If you truly need it to be an ArrayList you could write a quick utility method:

```
public static List<String> create(String... items) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(items.length);
    for (String item : items) {
        list.add(item);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: I should add that splix has a fine solution and you probably don't care about the actual implementation, but you will have to change you variable declaration from 'ArrayList<String> stuff' to 'List<String> stuff'

Answer (score 1):

If you're jamming 30-40 items into a list at compile time, that might be symptomatic of a greater ill. It depends a lot on what you're implementing. You can still use [split](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), if you really want though. Then just do a mass insert to your list.

Answer (score 0):

With the caveat that I'm just learning Java's Collections myself, the following compiles and runs for me:

```
import java.util.*;
class ArrayListStrings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] stuffArray = {"foo","bar","baz","boz","gaz","goz"};
        ArrayList<String> stuff = new ArrayList<String>();
        stuff.addAll(Arrays.asList(stuffArray));
        for (int i = 0; i < stuff.toArray().length; i++)
            System.out.println(stuff.toArray()[i]);   
    }
}
```

The output is:

> foo
>   bar
>   baz
>   boz
>   gaz
>   goz

Answer (score 0):

how abt the below code using http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

```
import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.*;

List<String> stuff = newArrayList("foo","bar","baz","boz","gaz","goz");
```